# Swift 2.1 - UIPickerView doesn't work well

Tags: ios, swift2, uipickerview, xcode7

I used the latest version of Xcode and also the latest version of Swift. I followed the steps of this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qN6U3UwNZc&index=20&list=PLPW-etRInDisaDUprk7XxlGpmerwkjb2o) but the pickerview doesn't show up in the simulator. Code is below. Could anybody helps me check that? Thanks a lot!

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

`@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var infoLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var picker: UIPickerView!

//var fruits: [String] = [String]()
var fruits = ["Pick a fruit" , "Apples" , "Oranges" , "Lemons" , "Blueberries"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "fruit.jpg")
   // picker.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}


func pickerView(pickeView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInCompoment component: Int) ->Int{
    return 5
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{
    return fruits[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){

    var fruitSelected = fruits[row]

    switch (fruitSelected){
    case "Apples":
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "apple.jpg")
        infoLabel.text = "These apples are red"

    case "Oranges":
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "orange.jpg")
        infoLabel.text = "These oranges are yellow"

    case "Lemons":
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Lemon.jpg")
        infoLabel.text = "These lemons are green"

    case "Blueberries":
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Blueberry.jpg")
        infoLabel.text = "These blueberries are blue"

    default:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "fruit.jpg")
        infoLabel.text = "Pick a fruit"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: PickerView is showing or not on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set your delegate and datasource correctly in storyboard, your issue is incorrect method signature. Notice the spelling mistakes in your method signature `(pickeView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInCompoment component: Int)`. Missing `r` in your `pickeView` and usage of `m` instead of `n` in your `numberOfRowsInCompoment`.

Try with below function and you should be all set...

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) ->Int{
    return 5
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't notice that when debugging last late night. Since I am the beginner of IOS developing. Do you have any suggestions of learning? Sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: You are most welcome @Aaron. I recollect that I had responded to someone on this [thread] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669622/learning-ios-programming-the-apple-way). giving links to start off with the learning process. This thread was eventually closed but checkout my answer if that helps!